# Joomla "Link Preview" (like the facebook feature)

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, joomla, joomla2.5

I am try to get for my joomla 2.5 website the feature of facebook "preview link". This feature should generate a preview when I enter a link in  my article (just like facebook does in the status field). I only need this features for link to text/images not to video.

I found this [link](http://lab.leocardz.com/facebook-link-preview-php--jquery/) but I am having difficulties to understand how I am suppose to implementing it into a joomla website.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To dictate what is used for a Facebook link in your content, you need to make use of the Facebook OpenGraph meta tags.

Take a look at this section of the Facebook Developers site, mainly Section 3: Use proper Open Graph tags.

[Link Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content)

The three you need for what you're after are:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MyContentTitle" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Enter your snippet here." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://myurl.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg " />
```

You can either statically set these for your website, or manipulate the template files for your articles, and echo out the article titles/images/snippets using PHP.

**//EDIT//**

After clarification from the comments, the easiest method would be to add tooltips using jQuery/jQuery UI:

[jQuery UI Tooltips](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

You can make the tooltips as large as you like, so you could add a preview of the article that is leads to.

Of course, you'll have to make changes to your site template to add this, and also include jQuery UI/jQuery to your template header, if it's not there already.

In addition to that, you'll need to use PHP to echo the article title, description and image within the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks Scarraban for your answer! I am sorry I haven't express myself clearly. I don't want to use facebook link in my joomla website but I am planning to use the facebook feature "preview link" for any kind of links (mainly newspaper articles). I have only cited facebook in my question as an example to better explain what I want to do.  (I have updated the question to make it more clear)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Arone. If you want people to be able to see "previews" of your content on your site, the best way would be to add CSS classes to all the links you want this to work on by changing your site template, then using [jQuery UI Tooltips](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to build a preview-looking element. You'll need to use PHP to print the relevant information, which would mean adding to your site template for article/category views. It's the simplest method of acheiving what you want, otherwise you're talking about building a whole Joomla plugin ;)

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify my answer in the comments.

Comment: Building a whole Joomla Plugin is well over my skills ;-) . I am right now trying to find a way to use the plugin on the link in the question (http://lab.leocardz.com/facebook-link-preview-php--jquery/) to generate a preview of an external link (which it is already doing well) and then to make it save this preview automatically in my /images/imagesarticles so I can find it in Image Manager in JCE editor. This seems like the easiest way (except the time consuming one saving the image, format and uploading it manually)